# Using well known tags or the 'ologies'

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

When considering previously tagged [birds](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds) and [fish](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) that I have renamed to their respective 'ologies' ([ornithology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ornithology) and [ichthyology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ichthyology)) in order to match the format of the 38 other ologies.  I feel that this will be of greater use in attracting experts in fields as these are the search terms they are more likely to use.

However this means that users who don't know the study formal names will struggle to find the tags.  This leaves us, I suppose, with two options (though other suggestions would be very happily received).

1. **Add synonyms for all the ologies**.  This would be the most user friendly for new users without in depth knowledge of scientific fields but would be the most intensive in the short run and it may be used extremely rarely.
2. **Manually re-tag as incorrect tags appear**.  This requires nil effort in the short term, however doesn't provide the benefits of automatically remapping for new users.  For example those users without the create new tag privilege may be unable to find the correct tag and either use an entirely wrong one or use really wide tags instead.

Which option sounds better?

Comment: How do we add synonyms?

Comment: Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2. However mods can add them outright so we can do it that way for the time being

Comment: Cool. Sounds like I have some work to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Synonyms

I prefer this approach.

Comment: Tags mentioned above have had synonyms created as well as mycology (fungus), which I hadn't previously noticed.