# Neuroscience or Neurology

Tags: discussion, tags

When tagging a question I was going to chose [neurology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neurology) - using the 'ology' [as previously discussed](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/using-well-known-tags-or-the-ologies) but [neuroscience](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neuroscience) is the preferred choice at present.

**Would anyone object to renaming *neuroscience* to *neurology* to avoid having a 'special case'?**

Comment: I think we're introducing some errors in terminology in some cases here by trying to use the more professional terms. But I'm not an expert in the definition of all those fields, so I don't necesarily notice those problems.

Comment: Neuroscience was already pushing the bounds of overlap with CogSci.SE; neurology would really be overstepping those bounds, no?

Answer (score 7):

Neuroscience is a far more general term, and probably the best one to use for tagging. Neurology is about disorders of the nervous system, while neuroscience is the study of the nervous system.

I'd say that neuroscience is at the correct level for tagging, and that we don't need a neurology tag so far.